# Iphone SDK: Play a "system sound"

Tags: iphone, audio, system

I want my IOSDevice to play a sound. Not just some sound that has a format, but a sound litteraly produced by the system. Pretty much like a buzzer or like a very old cellphone or the most famous of all - the NES!

How can i do that without using non-apple frameworks?

Comment: I would say that judging by apple's strict rules about affecting the "generic" user experience that might not actually be possible. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Why? I saw some other cool apps like nes-synth (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wwz87Ih4uc4&feature=channel_video_title) do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Apple won't let you access things such as system sounds.  You mentioned NESynth, but I believe that those sounds were produced with mp3 files, not through the system itself.  You could do something similar in your project.